# Why won't my JQuery show up in the div?

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

I'm  trying to get the $('#live-demo).fbwall to execute inside of the div in the facebook module. When I load the script on its own without the rest of the page content, it works fine. Am I doing something wrong that is conflicting now? I've only ever learned html and css and am trying to get the hang of some other languages now so I know I've got a lot of learning to do. Let me know if I need to post any css or js files. Thanks.

**Updated HTML to include changes made so far**

**EDIT Solved. Had one too many closing tags along with a few other errors.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="This Moment, Studio, Design, Web, Icons, Logos" />
    <meta name="description" content="This Moment Studio is a photography agency that takes amazing photos!" />
    <meta name="author" content="William McKenney" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all" />
    <title>This Moment Studio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Style" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#live-demo {
        width:500px;
        height:300px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#live-demo').fbWall({
                            id:'308294672531766',
                            accessToken:'323594700988256|g0Zr3Y_0tzS6TGo-DFjtNKfiJA8',
                            showGuestEntries:false,
                            showComments:false,
                            max:3,
                            timeConversion:12});
                        });
                </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- STATUS BAR -->
    <div id="status-bar">
        <div id="status-bar-content">
            <form action="#search" method="post" id="search-form">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="query" value="Search" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search!" />
                </p>
            </form>
            <div id="status-bar-commands">
                <p id="welcome">Welcome, Guest</p>
                <p id="action-bar">
                    <a href="#login" title="Login">Login</a>
                    <a href="#sitemap" title="Sitemap">Sitemap</a>
                    <a href="#license" title="License">License</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="#home" title="Home Page">This Moment</a></h1>
            <h2>Studio</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="content">
        <!-- TABS -->
        <ul id="tabs">
            <li id="previous">
                <a href="#previous" title="Previous">&lt;</a>
            </li>
            <li id="home" class="current">
                <a href="#home" title="Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="portfolio">
                <a href="#portfolio" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li id="about">
                <a href="#about" title="About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li id="contact">
                <a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li id="next">
                <a href="#next" title="Next">&gt;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- PAGE WRAPPER -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <!-- SLIDESHOW -->
            <div id="slideshow">
                <div id="slides">
                    <a href="#portfolio.work1" title="See details" class="thumb default-slide">
                        <img src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/336_siteFromScratch/./img/slideshow/1.png" alt="Flex Engine Web Design" class="slideshow-image" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="#portfolio.work2" title="See details" class="thumb">
                        <img src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/336_siteFromScratch/./img/slideshow/2.png" alt="Concept Labs Portfolio" class="slideshow-image" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="#portfolio.work3" title="See details" class="thumb">
                        <img src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/336_siteFromScratch/./img/slideshow/3.png" alt="Everlast Studio" class="slideshow-image" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="slideshow-commands">
                    <a href="#previous" title="Previous" id="previous-slide">&lt;</a>
                    <a href="#next" title="Next" id="next-slide">&gt;</a>
                    <h4>
                        <a href="#portfolio.work1" title="See details" id="slide-title">
                            Flex Engine Web Design
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- MESSAGE -->
            <div id="message">
                <h3>We build great websites!</h3>
                <p>
                    Curabitur nec sem in risus adipiscing feugiat. Etiam elementum malesuada purus.
                    Quisque nec mi eu mauris ornare aliquam. Praesent adipiscing,
                    metus sed luctus condimentum, quam turpis interdum tortor,
                    in dignissim magna urna tempor odio. Integer porttitor. Nam dolor urna,
                    ultricies vitae, porttitor ut, dignissim vitae, elit.
                </p>
                <p id="contact-info">
                    <span id="phone">+33 1 23 45 67 89</span>
                    <span id="address">
                        34, Avenue des Champs-<br />
                        Elys꦳, 75006, Paris,<br />
                        France
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- BLOG MODULE -->
        <div class="module" id="blog">
            <h4 class="module-header-bar">Latest entries from the blog</h4>
            <div class="blog-entry">
                <h5><a href="#blogentry1" title="Vivamus sed risus">Vivamus sed risus</a></h5>
                <p class="meta">By Jonathan Davidson - 05 / 08 / 09</p>
                <blockquote class="content">
                    <p>
                        Vivamus sed risus quis felis sagittis cursus. Duis blandit tristique turpis. Nulla feugiat vehicula metus.
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-entry">
                <h5><a href="#blogentry2" title="Pellentesque pulvinar">Pellentesque pulvinar</a></h5>
                <p class="meta">By The Team - 05 / 01 / 09</p>
                <blockquote class="content">
                    <p>
                        Pellentesque pulvinar dolor nec orci. Pellentesque scelerisque elit.
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-entry">
                <h5><a href="#blogentry3" title="Cras in nibh">Cras in nibh</a></h5>
                <p class="meta">By Nicholas Denman - 05 / 01 / 09</p>
                <blockquote class="content">
                    <p>
                        Quisque dapibus, justo a bibendum pellentesque, tellus felis cursus libero, posuere sodales diam ipsum in lorem.
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <p id="read-more-wrapper">
                <a href="#blog" title="Read More">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- FACEBOOK MODULE -->
        <div id="live-demo"> 
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-image"></div>
        <p id="footer-text">
            Copyright ɠ2009 Roadside Studio<br />
            All Rights Reserved
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you are experiencing? also wrap the code inside the `ready` handler

Comment: Anyone wondering about the .fbWall can check out the code from [Neosmart](http://neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall).

Comment: wrapping didn't help. when i get rid of all the other html and just have that one div it works fine. so not sure whats going on. how would i check for error?

Comment: Can you check the console tab in firebug if you're using firefox

Comment: possibly something with my last .js? is something not closed right with  <script src="jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.js" type="text/javascript" /> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your call in a .ready() handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#live-demo').fbWall({
                        id:'308294672531766',
                        accessToken:'323594700988256|g0Zr3Y_0tzS6TGo-DFjtNKfiJA8'                                   showGuestEntries:false,
                        showGuestEntries:false,
                        showComments:false,
                        max:3,
                        timeConversion:12});
            });
});
```

This happens because a browser executes the page in the same way you read it. So top-down it executes as quickly as possible which means your call executes before #live-demo may necessarily exists in the DOM.

Generally you want to wait for the entire DOM to load before firing any logic that happens on the page.

EDIT

This was not the issue as William has mentioned (and edited the question appropriately), but thanks to some good hunting, we have found the issue - can be traced in the comments.

Comment: had it like that to begin with. sorry that i forgot to put it back in before copy and paste. i have no idea why it won't work once that is in there. if i get rid of all the other html, it does exactly what i want. could it have to do with the div being nested inside of several others? shouldn't as long as i use ID right?

Comment: Just looking at your call again, scrolling right, i see you have  showGuestEntries:false, twice and no comma after your accessToken. Copy and paste issue?

Comment: This may sound silly, but can you try properly closing your script tags? with </script> I mean

Comment: just noticed that too. still didn't help but they weren't showing up in firebug.

Comment: Running out of ideas here. I downloaded the files just to have a look. Do you have the reference to loader-small.gif which is being used in the css. trying taking out .fb-wall.loading from the css to try it out

Comment: I have all the files so it shouldn't be an issue. i have an index2.html in the same directory with the bare minimum for html and it loads everything fine. for some reason with all the other page content it won't work though. not sure if maybe its the two css files conflicting as the parent divs are restricted in size i believe. not enough room for it to load maybe?

Comment: although by default it should be visible anyways. or at least with a scroll bar. i really have no idea. i'm completely stumped.

Comment: Ok I've just managed to piece together your latest update on my side. There was a syntax error in the javascript. Too many close brackets. Take out the last one (just above the script). Other than that, I have a copy and paste, fully functional on my side (short of a few images not loading).

Comment: lol fml. i've been staring at that for hours and didn't notice. thanks so much. i feel like an idiot. :) yeah i haven't added everything in yet. just trying to get the code all together first.

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help. Love them puzzles in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

always wrap your jquery code inside the ready handler so that it executes when the DOM has finished loading like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your fb plugin code here
});
```

or you can use the short hand method

```
$(function(){
//your code here

});
```

alternatively you can place the `js` code at the end of the document to ensure that it executes when the DOM has finished loading

Comment: i had it in there to start with but was playing around with a bunch of stuff and forgot to put it back in. still isn't making a difference. thanks for the info though!